# How to Parameterize a query with Like operator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to retrieve some data with below query and i Want to parameterize this.

```
select Col A,Col B,Col C,Col D
From TableA
where (COL A like '01%' or COL A like '02%')
```

I am using below query but i am not getting the output.

```
declare @p1 varchar ='01%',
        @p2 varchar ='02%'
select Col A,Col B,Col C,Col D
From TableA
where (COL A like @p1 or COL A like @p2)
```

Please suggest better way how to parameterize above query using sql server 2008r2.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you did not specify a length for your parameters, and they are being resolved as `varchar(1)`. You could see this with debugging 101, e.g.

```
DECLARE @p1 VARCHAR = '01%';
SELECT p1 = @p1, lenp1 = DATALENGTH(@p1);
```

Result:

```
p1   lenp1
---- -----
0    1
```

Try:

```
DECLARE @p1 VARCHAR(32) = '01%',
        @p2 VARCHAR(32) = '02%';
...
```

Please be explicit instead of lazy. Also use semi-colons to terminate statements.

- [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)
- [Ladies and gentlemen, start your semi-colons!](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)